# SVG width not filling on page scale

Tags: css, html, svg, responsive-design

I'm having a problem with a full width SVG (page width). When scaling my window it's creating a gap and when scaling further SVG is filled full width again. The screen is a image of the left end of the browser window.

[image: Left end of the browser window]

The SVG:

```
<svg class="line line-top" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1280 50">
    <polygon points="0 0 1280 0 1280 0 0 50"/>
</svg>
```

You can see it in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mpba7w6p/) try changing the viewbox height and the problem gap is starting to get smaller.

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks fine for me in Chrome

Comment: @Ian Try scaling your browser and watch the left black side.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the svg explicitly fill the page i.e.

```css
body {
    background:red;
    margin:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<svg fill="black" viewBox="0 0 1280 50" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin" width="100%" height="100%">
    <polygon points="0 0 1280 0 1280 0 0 50"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried but the SVG can't be a full page height item. http://jsfiddle.net/zujjof9q/, see where the content is going.

Comment: You'll need to make it a CSS background image then.

Comment: Yeah, but the thoughts about using this SVG is using the fill. So I only have to include the svg once.

Answer (score 0):

The bug isn't fixed or found but I created an simple CSS solution by pulling it outside the browser en overflowing it. I know it's not the solution but at least the client doesn't notice :)

Something like:

```
svg{
   fill: currentcolor;
   left: -7px;
   position: absolute;
   width: 103%;
}

.container{
   overflow:hidden;
}
```